# Unable To Call Second Element From a List in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to call the elements in **myList** but i only succeed to call first element. By running the below code i can see the length of the list is 3 but when i try to call second or third element i get "index out of range error".

I am not sure what is wrong, either the list itself is incorrect or i am trying to call it incorrrectly.

I really appreciate if someone could help me to resolve this issue to be able to call any element of **myList**.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

DateTime Date1 = DateTime(2019, 01, 01);
DateTime Date2 = DateTime(2019, 02, 02);
DateTime Date3 = DateTime(2019, 03, 03);

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  static List<Map<String, DateTime>> myList = [
    {"Text 1": Date1},
    {"Text 2": Date2},
    {"Text 3": Date3},
  ].toList();

  String x = myList[1].keys.elementAt(1);
  String y = myList[1].values.elementAt(1).toString();
  String z = myList.length.toString();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('$x'),
            Text('$y'),
            Text('$z'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it works fine. how did you call the second element ?

Comment: Don't show us the code you have that is working. Show us the code that **isn't** working.

Comment: @suhaibsalem i am calling second element by replacing the index "0" by "1" in the following lines of the code   ----> String x = myList[1].keys.elementAt(1);
  String y = myList[1].values.elementAt(1).toString();

Comment: @Abion47 yes you are right. i have updated the code now to the one that is not working. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code here. First:

```
static List<Map<String, DateTime>> myList = [
  {"Text 1": Date1},
  {"Text 2": Date2},
  {"Text 3": Date3},
].toList();
```

The `[...]` literal returns a list already, so the call to `toList()` is entirely redundant.

Next:

```
String x = myList[1].keys.elementAt(1);
String y = myList[1].values.elementAt(1).toString();
String z = myList.length.toString();
```

When you call `myList[1]`, you get the map `{"Text 2": Date2}`. Then you call `.keys.elementAt(1)`. The map only has one entry, so `keys` is going to return a list with a length of 1. Calling `elementAt(1)` attempts to get the second element of this one-element list, which will of course throw an `IndexOutOfRangeError`.

If you want to get the second element of your list, change the number in the indexer without changing the number in `elementAt`:

```
String x = myList[1].keys.elementAt(0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much and i really appreciate it. Your answer was very helpful and clear for me. The issue has been resolved now.

Comment: @flutter By calling myList[0] you will get the map {"Text 1": Date1} while calling myList[1] will return the map  {"Text 2": Date2} and calling myList[2] will return  {"Text 3": Date3}